# Read CSV file using Java for checking doublicates

Tags: java, csv

I have created a program that writes on a CSV file specific info: ID, name, average.

I want to add data again, but before adding it, I want to check that if the file already has the data I would not allow it to upload.

Note: I have already created a method that checks the data entered by the user and it won't allow the user to add it if the ID is already used, but it works only on the command line, so I want to be able to connect it to the file reader as well.

Note: Still I'm still new to reading and writing files.

I'm going to add two things:

1. The writing File
2. The check method.

Writing the file:

````
public void printStudents() throws IOException {
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("studentList.csv", true);
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);

    for (int i = 0; i < this.myStudents.size(); i++) {
        printWriter.print(
                this.myStudents.get(i).getIDNumber() + "," +
                        this.myStudents.get(i).getName() + ","
                        + this.myStudents.get(i).getGPA() + "\n");
    }
    printWriter.close();```
````

Here is the check method:

```
private int findStudent(String studentName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.myStudents.size(); i++) {
        Student student = this.myStudents.get(i);
        if (student.getIDNumber().equals(studentName)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;

}
```

Note: this methods shows that if the "find student method has returned -1, the student can be added successfully".

Comment: Not really sure what is the specific question. Con you clarify what issue you are facing with the given code? any errors? if not errors but unexpected output then may add some minimal dataset as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a LinkedHashMap to save the data from the file, using the student name, the id number and the GPA as a unique key:

```java
//Here you can read the old CSV file
//...
//Then read each student line by line:
LinkedHashMap<String, Student> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Student>();
for (int i = 0; i < this.myStudents.size(); i++) {
   String tempKey= this.myStudents.get(i).getIDNumber() + this.myStudents.get(i).getName() + this.myStudents.get(i).getGPA();
   if(!hashMap.containsKey(tempKey)){
       hashMap.put(tempKey, this.myStudents.get(i))
   }

//Here is the check method
private boolean findStudent(Student student, LinkedHashMap<String, Student> hashMap) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    String theKey = student.getIDNumber() + student.getName() + student.getGPA();
    if(hashMap.containsKey(theKey)){ 
        isFound = true;
    }
    return isFound;
}
```